# Creating indexes on large tables in MySQL (MariaDB) takes a verrry looong time

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have a table with a few billion rows of data and I am trying to build 5 indexes on it at once. The table format is MyISAM to save space. Once I build the indexes this will be a static table, I just need it to be read only.

I created the indexes using this command:

alter table links8 add index(uid,tid), add index (date), add index (tid), add index (userid), add index (updated,uid,tid,userid,date);

The command has been running for over 45 days. You read that right: 45 DAYS. I can see that the temp files are still being accessed, it isn't a dead query.

My question is: wtf? Seems like it should take a few hours at most to sort and build an index even with a few billion rows.

Since I have a static table, is there another storage engine that makes sense to use? Innodb takes up way too much space.

Comment: 45 days? Good grief.

Comment: That is a lot, however I can't say I'm supprised. Few billion rows is a lot too. MySql is known to fail on edge use cases like that.. YOu can try building one index at a time. If you can use postgres, try that too, but it may get just as slow. In the end this just may be the case for hadoop and solr.

Comment: I need quick access to the data queried in a few different ways, and often sorted. If I didn't need the sorts I think SOLR (or ElasticSearch which I prefer) would be a good choice, but the field caches would be enormous for sorting if I went that route. We aren't talking about a ridiculous amount of raw data here, only 43GB in the MYD file, this shouldn't be so darn hard.

Comment: As interesting as it was to let that query continue to run, I decided to kill it. I was a bit afraid that it might just thrash the disk to death. I am trying another route, I created a new empty table with the indexes already in place and I am attempting to insert all of the data with one statement. Will it take just as long? Anyone taking bets?

Answer (score 0):

45 days doesn't seem right, because in that time, MySQL is bound to do something, and that something is likely either consuming RAM or storage, likely both, which means that you should have run out of either at some point.
I'd assume it's RAM, because that usually is where things get sparse ;)

Now, you're absolutely right, sorting a few billion values in memory shouldn't take ages. Sorting a few billion values that are the concatenated values in `(updated,uid,tid,userid,date)` though most likely doesn't happen in RAM. Assuming `updated` and `date` are of type `datetime`, they take 8 bytes each; `uid`,`tid`,`userid` would normally be 32 bit ints, but since your table has > 2**32 entries (I'm assuming that), unique ID's would be 8 byte long, too. So one value of type `(updated,uid,tid,userid,date)` would be 40B long.

Now throw in let's say 5 billion of these; you get 200 GB of pure row data that you'll need to sort to build an index. Assuming you're not doing this on some huge machine, you obviously need to swap out parts of these values to disk -- since you see temporary files appear, my wild guess is that this is happening, and MySQL is actively doing that itself. Now, sorting algorithms that work on parts of the rows iteratively are much slower, because first you sort all parts, then you mix up the parts in a manner that's better sorted than before, than you re-partition your data, you sort your parts ... with storing and loading from disk in between.

By the way, a 45 day lasting memory operation is likely to be prone to memory bit errors, if no correctional measures are taken (basically, use ECC for this kind of task, or you end up with indexed, corrupted data).

MySQL themselves [suggest](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/multiple-column-indexes.html) that you just build a special MD5 index that takes the hash of your search tuple and looks for that, since sorting 128bit (==16 byte) MD5 hashes might be easier than sorting 5*8Byte == 40*8 bit == 320bit long composite rows.

Comment: I don't think an MD5 index would work for me in this case as I often need to pull it out sorted (hence the compound index).

Is there any trick I can use to build the index offline using myisamchk?

Answer (score 0):

I found a better solution.

I created a new table with the indexes already in place then issued an insert from one table to the other. The way this works is it fills the MYD (raw data file) up and then creates the indexes after that. Once it has started creating the indexes I killed the query. Then on the filesystem I used myisamchk to repair the table manually.

That command looked like this:

myisamchk --force --fast --update-state --key_buffer_size=2000M --sort_buffer_size=2000M --read_buffer_size=10M --write_buffer_size=10M TABLE.MYI

And the whole thing took less than 12 hours and the data looks good!

UPDATE:

Here is the flow summarized.

create table2 indentical to table1 with indexes;

insert into table2 select * from table1;

once the MYD file is full and it starts on the MYI file kill the query

then shutdown mysql and run the myisamchk query and restart mysql

OR

copy table2.MYD and table2.MYI to table3.MYD and table3.MYI, then run myisamchk, then copy table2.frm to table3.frm and change the permissions, when it's all done you should be able to access table3 without a restart of mysql

Comment: It should be noted that in my.cnf I have the myisam_sort_buffer_size set to 2500m, sort_buffer_size set to 400m, and key_buffer set to 1600m. I am not sure which sort buffer size it actually uses though.